# object_id() vs sys.objects

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, sql-scripts

I use database scripts where I check for the existence of a Stored Procedure then drop it then create it.

Which of the following would be more efficient for checking and dropping SPs
**Option 1**

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[myStoredProc]',N'P'))
  DROP PROCEDURE dbo.myStoredProc;
```

**Option 2**

```
IF OBJECT_ID (N'dbo. myStoredProc',N'P') IS NOT NULL
  DROP PROCEDURE dbo.myStoredProc;
```

I have decided to use the second one due to obvious reasons, is there any reason why I should go for the first option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there are no compelling reasons to use sys.objects directly. As a matter of fact, use of these sys views is being discouraged - so if you can avoid it, do so!

Instead, INFORMATION_SCHEMA schema views are supposed to be used where possible - this is a standard SQL-92 mechanisms for exposing metadata about your server (rather than a Microsoft-specific way of using the sys.* views).

Marc

Answer (score 3):

The tide has changed. Current policy from MSDN is that sys.objects should be used instead of INFORMATION_SCHEMA views, because the sys views have more information than the latter.